# GPS Speed is wrong

Tags: java, android, gps, location

I have much differences (~20%) between real speed and the GPS speed. But first let me show my Code:

```
private LocationManager locationMgr;
private String locationProvider;
```

...

```
// Location Manager for GPS
this.locationMgr = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
this.locationProvider = locationMgr.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
this.locationMgr.requestLocationUpdates(this.locationProvider, 0, 1.0f, this);
```

In the location listener:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Get speed from location
    this.speed = location.getSpeed();

    // Set speed TextView
    this.gpsVelo.setText(Helper.doubleToStringParser(this.speed, Constants.KMPH, null));
}
```

As result I get a speed which is different from the speed which is shown by my car. I know the speedometer is +3-5% in a car, but I've got 20% and more. So I've tested with an other GPS-App and it shows me a correct Value. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you post the wrong values vs the expected correct ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GPS does not provide accurate speeds at very low speed values.
At that low speeds, different algorithms (using averaging etc.) may report diff speeds. 
Over 10 - 20km/h it should be very acurate up to 1%.
Test it in a car or train, you should got the same integral km/h value for all GPS devices, when the train runs at least 50 km/h.

Comment: Yeah I was just driving up to 30 km/h and so the gps speed was not correct. But yesterday I drive 120 and the gps speed was 112 which is okay, I think. Anybody has an idea to handle slower speeds? In my Opinion I need to trigger the Location Manager to get the Location more often. But how can I do that?

Comment: At 120 km/h GPS Speed is accurate to 0,1 km/h. Trust me. Your tachometer of your car is the device which can be wrong by about 7%. calibrated tachometer (police) have 3% acuracy. A good idea to proove is to look at a navigatoin device. You will se that you always will be within 1km/h of the navi.

Comment: Slower speed: Just ignore them, design you app that it does not evaluate lower speeds. or try to average about the last 5 seconds.

Comment: yeah I do know that, the 120 km/h was shown by my car, the 112km/h was shown by my App. So it's all right. For slower speeds I'll try to use the last 3 - 5 seconds. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

location.getSpeed() returns the speed in m/s. If you need it in km/h you will need `double speed = location.getSpeed()*3.6;`.

Comment: The factor of 3.6 means 360% not 20%, so this answer should not be the solution

Comment: The factor of 3.6 means a failure of 260%, if your invert input and output it's ~72%. It's not absolutly clear, what ray means with difference. But he obviously wants the speed in km/h (In his Code:Constants.KMPH) and getSpeed give you m/s. So if it's not the whole solution it's at least a part of it.

Comment: I had this factor already in the doubleToStringParser Method. Sorry for not showing these code fragment, so this should be fine.